# What's Typescript's issue with document.getElementbyID?

Tags: typescript

Please someone choose a better title, because I frankly don't know how to title this one.

What I'm trying to do, is to get Textarea's content as string (for use with NW.js file functions as I'm writing an app that does stuff on flat files) and I'm using following code to do that:

```
let file = document.getElementById("txt").value;
```

It works after being compiled to JS just fine. However, the TypeScript compiler complains about the value part:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's raison d'être is to apply static typing to JavaScript-like code. `document.getElementById` returns `HTMLElement`, which doesn't have `value` (after all, it could be any kind of HTML element), so TypeScript warns you you're using a property that `HTMLElement` doesn't have. TypeScript can't know that the specific element you're getting is an `HTMLInputElement` (which has `value`) unless you tell it it is via casting (technically, a [*type assertion*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)):

```
let file = (document.getElementById("txt") as HTMLInputElement).value;
// or
let file = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("txt")).value;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification.